# Why can't i add string to startup parameters section?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I installed SQL Server 2012 and then I tried to start SQL Service but I got an error.

I looked at Event Log I saw this error:

> initerrlog: Could not open error log file ''. Operating system error = 3(The system can not find the path specified.).

I googled this error and found some solutions that are the same. They say that add parameters to startup parameters section that exists in the *`*Properties**` of SQL Service `**Advanced**` section.

However this section is disabled to add string. How can i add some values to there? or Are there any other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: What solutions? Why do you think they apply to your problem? SQL Server doesn't need any changes to command line switches to work. SQL Server's service should start automatically, why did you have to start it manually? Were there any other error messages? What was their *complete* content? Such an error indicates a serious problem, something that can't be solved simply by adding a command-line switch. Eg, a failed or incomplete installation, a corrupt drive, specifying an external drive that is now missing.

Comment: BTW, at least two of the pages I've found googling for this message mention a *permissions* problem and advice to ensure the service account you used has access to the data/log files you specified. This isn't something that can be fixed by changing the command line, but it can be made [much worse](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=154391)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is not on the [Advanced] tab it has its own tab named as [Startup Parameters].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not an answer. You should delete this and make it a comment.